# Display status based on condition in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i am trying to display status yes or no based on string of status in log table.

SQL Query

```
SELECT  Data.user_id,

  CASE WHEN log.user_id = Data.user_id  and log.status like 'checked%' THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO' END AS Status1 ,

  CASE WHEN log.user_id = Data.user_id  and log.status like 'UNCHECKED%' THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO' END AS Status2

from Data

LEFT JOIN log
    on log.user_id = Data.user_id and log.log_id = '23'

GROUP BY Data.user_id;
```

Data Table:

```
user_id  
23
24
25
```

log Table:

```
user_id   status          log_id
23        checked_REC       23
23        UNCHECKED_REC     23
25        checked_REC       23
26        clicked_REC       12
27        valid_REC         13
28        sesionout_REC     14
```

I need to display as

```
user_id  Status1  Status2 
23         YES       YES
24         NO        NO
25         YES       NO
```

But now i am getting

```
user_id  Status1  Status2 
23         YES       NO
24         NO        NO
25         YES       NO
```

What should i do, to get required status?

Comment: as far as you are using log.user_id=Data.user_id in join clause, you don't need to add it to the case. and, you're grouping by ID two rows with different Status1,2 values. and I don't know if it matters but there is an space after ℅ in 'UNCHECKED% '

Comment: Just to emphazise again what mcNets correctly stated: you have to remove the space in 'UNCHECKED% '.

Comment: @Solarflare after removing white spaces geting wrong result as shown above

Comment: You didn't add the `log_id` column to your output of your log table. And you are grouping incorrectly. Try `... CASE WHEN min(log.status) like 'checked%' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Status1, CASE WHEN max(log.status) like 'UNCHECKED%' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Status2 ...`, although you actually should do two joins, one for each status. But the case will work too, as long as you just have these two states.

Comment: @Solarflare  check my edited log table. output doesnot change by putting min(log.status) and max(log.status). and How you say i am grouping wrongly.Can you explain a bit on this? and here i think it is fetching for one row only, even if there exist two rows of checked and unchecked for single user_id.

Comment: @Solarflare I got it, thanks for sharing knowledge and time

Answer (score 0):

i got expected output by below query

```
SELECT  Data.user_id,
MAX(IF(log.status like 'checked%', 'YES', 'NO')) Status1,
MAX(IF(log.status like 'UNCHECKED%', 'YES', 'NO')) Status2
from Data

LEFT JOIN log
    on log.user_id = Data.user_id and log.log_id = '23'

GROUP BY Data.user_id;
```